# WP rest api jwt auth

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, jwt

I would like use WP REST API auth with this plugin : https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth

I get the token with this req on POST : http://localhost/wp_rest/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token

But I can't do the request for post mehod:
localhost/wp_rest/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

I get the error **403**:

```
{
    "code": "rest_forbidden"
    "message": "You don't have permission to do this."
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

In my header I have this :

```
Authorization: Bearer
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3RcL3dwX3Jlc3QiLCJpYXQiOjE0NTAzNDEwMTgsIm5iZiI6MTQ1MDM0MTAxOCwiZXhwIjoxNDUwOTQ1ODE4LCJkYXRhIjp7InVzZXIiOnsiaWQiOiIxIn19fQ.rGNPsU4EocClWLYWaSDs1hDJMODszg-eKfqnKSEsiw0
```

I'm trying with localhost/wp_rest/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate but I get this error:

```
{
    "code": "jwt_auth_no_auth_header",
    "message": "Authorization header not found.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you did not include Authorization headers in your request. You need to add `'Authorization': 'Bearer PLACE_TOKEN_HERE'` in your request headers.

As a sample:

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: window.location.href + 'wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + TOKEN_GOES_HERE
    }
    data: DATA TO PASS GOES HERE
}
$http(req);
```

Comment: I am using it in Flutter app and doing like this 
`
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Authorization': '$urlHeader',
    };
    var url = new Uri.http(
      Webisite.url,
      "/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token",
    );
    var client = http.Client();
    var response = await client.post(
      url,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      body: {
        "username": email,
        "social_login": "true",
      },
    );
`
But it is giving me error to revalidate? how to solve this

Answer (score 4):

If the answer provided by Leo Gono and Tunaki still doesn't solve your problem, make sure you've added the [following code](https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth#eable-php-http-authorization-header) to your `.htaccess` if you're using Apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Make sure to put those lines before the last line with an "[L]" in your .htaccess or else it won't get processed.

It's possible that the Authorisation header gets discarded by server of framework settings. (I've had to change the htaccess for Laravel)

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into similar problems while setting up the same plugin so I created a video detailing the process I followed to quickly launch a test environment, install the plugin, perform the necessary setup for the plugin to work and then validate its functionality.

Here it is: https://youtu.be/Mp7T7x1oxDk

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. My solution was simple.

Using the tool (in my case postman (https://www.getpostman.com)), I selected to add the Authentication header (forcing the header) manually. You might want to set it manually when using code, under the HTTP Header section (not as a paramater, just in case :) ).

[image: Checked enable Authentication header]

Kind regards,
Reinhard